# How to color the border and the rectangle of different colors? SDL

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have a responsible function for drawing a rectangle on the screen, it is inside the main loop of my program, it does this:

```
DrawRetangle (SDL_Renderer * Renderer, SDL_Rect MyRect) {

    // Clean the renderer
    SDL_RenderClear (Renderer);

   // Position x, y, width and height of the rectangle.
    MyRect = {x, y, width, height};

    // Rectangle border color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

    // Draw the edges of the rectangle
    SDL_RenderDrawRect (Renderer, & MyRect);

    // Color from within the rectangle
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (Renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    // Fill in the rectangle
    SDL_RenderFillRect (Renderer, & MyRect);

    // Show in window
    SDL_RenderPresent (Renderer);

}
```

Note that I am trying to draw a rectangle with a black border and filled with white, but it gets all black, I know I can solve this, cleaning, drawing the border, showing, cleaning, drawing the interior and showing, however if I tier many rectangle , This would be bad, is there a better way to do this?

> **Up 1:**

To function would it be just this way, as below?

```
DrawRetangle (SDL_Renderer * Renderer, SDL_Rect MyRect) {

    // Clean the renderer 1
    SDL_RenderClear (Renderer);

   // Position x, y, width and height of the rectangle.
    MyRect = {x, y, width, height};

    // Rectangle border color
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

    // Draw the edges of the rectangle
    SDL_RenderDrawRect (Renderer, & MyRect);

    // Show in window 1
    SDL_RenderPresent (Renderer);

    // Clean the renderer 2
    SDL_RenderClear (Renderer);

    // Color from within the rectangle
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (Renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    // Fill in the rectangle
    SDL_RenderFillRect (Renderer, & MyRect);

    // Show in window 2
    SDL_RenderPresent (Renderer);

}
```

> **Up 2:**

Another solution I found was to call the function below twice, creating a rectangle on top of another, the one inside a little smaller, thus looking like a border. But I still do not think it should be the best way to do it.

```
DrawRetangle (SDL_Renderer * Renderer, SDL_Rect MyRect, int x, int, y, int width, int height, int r, int g, int b, int a) {

       // Position x, y, width and height of the rectangle.
        MyRect = {x, y, width, height};


        // Color from within the rectangle
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (Renderer, r, g, b, a);

           // Clean the renderer
        SDL_RenderClear (Renderer);

        // Fill in the rectangle
        SDL_RenderFillRect (Renderer, & MyRect);

        // Show in window
        SDL_RenderPresent (Renderer);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

before drawing filled rectangle change the size and position of your rectangle.
and then try .

```
Myrect->x+=borderSize; //whatever size you want
Myrect->y+=borderSize;
Myrect->h-=(borderSize*2);
Myrect->w-=(borderSize*2);
    // Color from within the rectangle
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor (Renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);

// Fill in the rectangle
SDL_RenderFillRect (Renderer, & MyRect);
```

Comment: I do not understand, I'm already doing this, right? `Rect = {x, y, width, height};`

Comment: I understood, when it fills then it also preeenche the border, and it would look like this:

`Myrect.x + = borderSize;
Myrect.y + = borderSize;
Myrect.h- = borderSize;
Myrect.w- = borderSize;`

I think that this does not work, you're moving in x and y, decreasing in hewo value of borderSize, which would leave the sides and bottom without border, and something quite wrong in doing this, or I'm not seeing well, Value of borderSize and the border increases.